# @PostConstruct doesn't seem to be invoked, resolving in path error

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

In my jsf application I have a bean like this

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped 
public class myBean implements Serializable {

 private String path;

 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
     path= "defaultpage";
 }
}
```

(with setPath and getPath) and a xhtml file with this element:

```
<ui:include src="directory/#{myBean.path}.xhtml" />
```

when i browse to the page, the browser show an error about "directory/.xhtml" not being a valid path.
Am I wrong assuming myBean.path is never being setted? Anyway, how can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by setting a breakpoint, then you are **sure** if it is invoked or not. Secondly run you application in development mode. Thirdly check your `@ManageBean` annotation, is it the correct one? Forthly if you are using jsf 2.1 or up, please start using CDI managed beans instead of JSF managed ones. And last but not least, set a breakpoint in the getter (you do have a getter do you?)

Comment: @Kukeltje yes it was not invoked and yes I have a getter. Changing ManagedBean with Named solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Then you most likely had the wrong `@ManageBean` import. And keep in mind that `@Named` uses a different `@ViewScoped` than `@ManagedBean`

Answer (score 0):

To close the loop the issue was that the wrong annotations were being used.  The following are the correct annotations and imports for JSF 2.2+.

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

@Named
@ViewScoped 
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
```

Comment: There is a duplicate of this. For most of these generic things there is. I know you cannot vote for duplicates yet, but try to find them and add them as a comment to the question. Keeps stackoverflow clean.... cheeers

Comment: I appreciate you decided to answer.  For some reason I'm not able to find javax.enterprise.context using Maven, though.

Comment: That is for JSF 2.2.  You must be using 2.1 you need to use @javax.faces.view.ViewScoped

Comment: Actually, I'm using 2.2.17

Comment: Updated my answer I forgot javax.faces.view.ViewScoped is the correct scope always.